# Example.js?id=fhfhf&key=hfbhdvbh How to get the id and key parameters from its own js?

Tags: php, javascript, parameters

how can i get the id and key in this example script.

```
<script src=sample.jswidget?id=fhgfgd&key=yfgdghhdhdg type="text/javascript"/>
```

Comment: I think he means how to pull the parameters passed to a js file through something like this  Example.js?id=fhfhf&key=hfbhdvbh

Comment: yah that's it.How can I extract those parameters on its own js.?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use your .js by writing :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Example.js?id=fhfhf&key=hfbhdvbh"></script">
```

Which is wrong.

Javascript uses global variables.

You can write :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var id = "fhfhf";
   var key = "hfbhdvbh";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Example.js"></script">
```

`id` and `key` will be known in your Example.js file.

Comment: I just saw it somewhere before...Actually google api is using it as a key.

Comment: Can you post any piece of code ? I'm not sure to totally understand your problem.

Comment: Those parameters are sent to the web server. Web server can do anything with them. For example, generate javascript dynamically with the values of them (using php or another server-side programming language)

Answer (score 0):

This might work, but I haven't tested it

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
if(scripts) {
    var src = scripts[scripts.length-1].src;
    src = src.match(/\?id=(.*)\&key=(.*)\&?/);
    var params = {id: src[1], key: src[2]};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used that on an extreme case that i needed the javascript to be different on every reload (not the values, some loops and the javascript was generated by a jsp page).
But i only used one parameter with a known name.

```
var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
var parms = query.split('RS=');
```

but I had a different page that i pulled in with jquery

Answer (score 0):

I got it work now guys. I just change the

> **example.js?**id=fhfhf&key=hfbhdvbh
>
> **adding the .js with .php extension**
>
> **example.js.php?**id=fhfhf&key=hfbhdvbh

And inside the example.js.php

```
<?php

var id = echo $_GET['id'];
var key = echo $_GET['id'];

?>
```